# Gem `activity_notification` does not create a new record after getting triggered by an active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

The gem `activity_notification` is not creating/triggering after I've configured it according to the documentation. I've tried to create the notification in the event of a user creating a comment or replying to an existing comment, but the gem is not created/triggered. Please help me figure out why.

Here's my code

## Model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  audited

  with_options dependent: :destroy do |assoc|
    assoc.has_many :forums, class_name: 'Communication::Forum'
    assoc.has_many :favorited_forums, class_name: 'Communication::FavoritedForum'
    assoc.has_many :comments
    assoc.has_many :likes
  end

  acts_as_target
end
```

## Model Forum

```
class Communication::Forum < ApplicationRecord
  audited
  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_commentable

  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  has_many :favorited_forums, class_name: "Communication::FavoritedForum"

end
```

## Model Comment

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  acts_as_nested_set scope: [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

  acts_as_notifiable :users,
    targets: ->(comment, key) {
      ([comment.commentable.user] + [comment.user]).uniq
    }

end
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Can you add it to the Question please?

Comment: Hmm, my question is "why it wont create/trigger the gem" even i've configure as their documentation

Comment: Can you add a link to the configuration manual you've tried and the relevant part of the configuration you are actually using?